# ¿Hay alguna forma de hacer este código JavaScript de una forma más limpia?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, ecmascript-2015

Pido perdon si este tipo de preguntas no se peude hacer. Me gustaría saber si este código de javascript en NodeJS se puede hacer de una forma más limpia.

```
const os = require('os');
const express = require('express');
const pug = require('pug');
const app = express();
const port = 80;

var hostname = os.hostname();
var platform = os.platform();
var cpu = os.arch();
var cpus = os.cpus();

var model = cpus[0].model;
var speed = cpus[0].speed;


app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
  res.render("index", {
    hostname:hostname,
    platform:platform,
    cpu:cpu,
    model:model,
    speed:speed
  });
  res.end();
}).listen(port, 'localhost', () => {
  console.log("Aplicacion escuchada en el puerto: "+port);
})
```

Comment: Buenas, desde mi punto de vista creo que es un ejemplo muy pequeñito, por lo tanto simplificar eso más es complicado, aún así quizás quedaría más limpio ya que lo has sacado todo en variables y constantes (que es una buena práctica), sacar las opciones del render en un objeto JSON a parte. Me gustaría ver las opciones que te dan el resto de usuarios. Saludos!!

Comment: Dices encerrar las opciones del json aparte y encerrarlo en una variable para luego pasarlo? Es buena idea y es mas limpio, gracias por el aporte.

Comment: Sí, eso es. var (o let si usas ES6). Es un placer ser de ayuda.